# Docker-MySQL5.6 unknown variable lower_case_table_names=1

Tags: docker, global-variables, mysql-5.6

I want to set the variable **lower_case_table_names**  to 1 in the MySQL 5.6 docker container.

I put the variable in the **my.cnf** file **[mysqld]** under **/etc/mysql** in the container.

After stopping the container it didn't start giving this error:

> unknown variable lower_case_table_names=1

So what I'm asking is there is an other way to set this variable to 1 ?

Answer (score 11):

I hope you already found your answer, but something like this works:
`docker run -p 3306:3306 mysql:5.6 -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=1 mysqld --lower_case_table_names=1`

For docker-compose, this works:

```
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    command: --lower_case_table_names=1
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'test'
```

Comment: This was life savior for me

Comment: Alternatively you can use a custom MySQL configuration file as in https://wiki.elexis.info/Mysql_docker_container but  
environment:
      EXTRA_OPTS: '--lower_case_table_names=1'
not work

Comment: When I use this setting, failed with the following error.
```db_1  | 2021-07-25T17:03:24.218116Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011087] [Server] Different lower_case_table_names settings for server ('1') and data dictionary ('0').
db_1  | 2021-07-25T17:03:24.218574Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
db_1  | 2021-07-25T17:03:24.218907Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting```

Comment: Interesting solution, however when running `docker-compose up db`, it show this: ```[Warning] [MY-010160] [Server] lower_case_table_names was set to 2, even though your the file system '/var/lib/mysql/' is case sensitive.  Now setting lower_case_table_names to 0 to avoid future problems```. So problem persists still. Seems that if your file system is case sensitive then you can't set the value to 2.